# Could not fetch metadata for bootstrap@git+ssh

Tags: angular, angularjs, git, github, npm

I'm trying to install angular devkit and other dependencies using npm install. The following error is seen.

```
Could not fetch metadata for bootstrap@git+ssh://git@github.com/gios/Web-Standards-Bootstrap.git#05a343dddce91dd1577025267e07a35a5e GitUnknownError: An unknown git error occurred
npm WARN old lockfile     at makeError (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\git\lib\make-error.js:28:13)
npm WARN old lockfile     at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\git\lib\spawn.js:36:26 {
npm WARN old lockfile   cmd: 'git',
npm WARN old lockfile   args: [
npm WARN old lockfile     '--no-replace-objects',
npm WARN old lockfile     'ls-remote',
npm WARN old lockfile     'ssh://git@github.com/gios/Web-Standards-Bootstrap.git'
npm WARN old lockfile   ],
npm WARN old lockfile   signal: null,
npm WARN old lockfile   stdout: '',
npm WARN old lockfile   stderr: 'git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n' +
npm WARN old lockfile     'fatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n' +
npm WARN old lockfile     '\n' +
npm WARN old lockfile     'Please make sure you have the correct access rights\n' +
npm WARN old lockfile     'and the repository exists.\n'
npm WARN old lockfile 
}
```

Comment: Do you have permission to use ssh access to `ssh://git@github.com/gios/Web-Standards-Bootstrap.git`?

Answer (score 0):

There could be two possibilities:

1. The mentioned git repository doesn't exist/deleted from the github.
2. Those who are trying to access the git repository doesn't have access to it.